# Why I keep getting error in between command lines?

Tags: upgrade, fedora

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdw8v.png)This time I was trying to upgrade my 36 Fedora version. The command made it to its end but i keep getting error in between. And i think these can have affect the system itself.

This is the command I tried :
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdw8v.png)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I believe you already did: `sudo dnf clean all` and `sudo dnf update`. Post result of: `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo`.